# How to read csv with multiple quoted delimiters in single field?

Tags: python, csv

I'd like to be able to split a string which contains the delimiter quoted multiple times. Is there an argument to handle this type of string with the csv module? Or is there another way to process it?

```py
text = '"a,b"-"c,d","a,b"-"c,d"'
next(csv.reader(StringIO(text), delimiter=",", quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE))
```

Expected output: `['"a,b"-"c,d"', '"a,b"-"c,d"']`

Actual output: `['"a', 'b"-"c', 'd"', '"a', 'b"-"c', 'd"']`

**EDIT:**
The example above is simplified, but apparently too simplified as some comments provided solutions for the simplified version but not for the full version. Below is the actual data I want to process.

```py
import csv
text = '"3-Amino-1,2,4-triazole"-text-0-"3-Amino-1,2,4-triazole"-CD-0,"3-Amino-1,2,4-triazole"-text-0-"3-Amino-1,2,4-triazole"-LS-0'
next(csv.reader(StringIO(text), delimiter=",", quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE))
```

Expected output

```py
[
  '"3-Amino-1,2,4-triazole"-text-0-"3-Amino-1,2,4-triazole"-CD-0',
  '"3-Amino-1,2,4-triazole"-text-0-"3-Amino-1,2,4-triazole"-LS-0'
]
```

Actual output

```py
[
  '"3-Amino-1',
  '2',
  '4-triazole"-text-0-"3-Amino-1',
  '2',
  '4-triazole"-CD-0','"3-Amino-1',
  '2', '4-triazole"-text-0-"3-Amino-1',
  '2',
  '4-triazole"-LS-0'
]
```

Comment: I cannot make this assumption unfortunately. I'll update the example!

Comment: Where is the data coming from? Can you tell us a bit more about the format?

Comment: @Thomas you are right I did not fully update the example. It is updated now.

Comment: Try `print(next(csv.reader(StringIO(text.replace('","', '";"')), delimiter=';', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)))`

Comment: @MartinEvans looks like I simplified the example too much. Your code works for the simplified example I provided but not for the full example. I'll update the question with the full example.

Answer (score 1):

I'll only answer the first part of your question: there is no way to do this with the built-in `csv` module.

Looking at the CPython source code, `quotechar` option is [only processed](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/09eb81711597725f853e4f3b659ce185488b0d8c/Modules/_csv.c#L651) at the start of a field:

```c
    case START_FIELD:
        /* expecting field */
        ...
        else if (c == dialect->quotechar &&
                 dialect->quoting != QUOTE_NONE) {
            /* start quoted field */
            self->state = IN_QUOTED_FIELD;
        }
        ...
        break;
```

Inside a field, [there is no such check](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/09eb81711597725f853e4f3b659ce185488b0d8c/Modules/_csv.c#L697):

```c
    case IN_FIELD:
        /* in unquoted field */
        if (c == '\n' || c == '\r' || c == '\0') {
            /* end of line - return [fields] */
            if (parse_save_field(self) < 0)
                return -1;
            self->state = (c == '\0' ? START_RECORD : EAT_CRNL);
        }
        else if (c == dialect->escapechar) {
            /* possible escaped character */
            self->state = ESCAPED_CHAR;
        }
        else if (c == dialect->delimiter) {
            /* save field - wait for new field */
            if (parse_save_field(self) < 0)
                return -1;
            self->state = START_FIELD;
        }
        else {
            /* normal character - save in field */
            if (parse_add_char(self, module_state, c) < 0)
                return -1;
        }
        break;
```

There is a check for `quotechar` while the parser is in the `IN_QUOTED_FIELD` state; however, upon encountering a quote, it goes back to the `IN_FIELD` state indicating we're inside an unquoted field. So this is possible:

```
>>> import csv
>>> import io
>>> print(next(csv.reader(io.StringIO('"a,b"cd,e'))))
['a,bcd', 'e']
```

But once the parser has reached the end of the initial quoted section, it will consider any subsequent quotes as part of the data. I don't know if this behaviour is to conform with any (written or unwritten) CSV specification, or if it's just a bug.

Comment: Even though this doesn't solve my problem, thank you for providing insight into why the csv module is not able to do this!

Answer (score 1):

The data is in a non-standard format and so any solution would need to be tested on the full dataset. A possible workaround could be to first replace `,"` characters with `;"` and then simply split it on the `;`. This could be done without using CSV or RE:

```
tests = [
    '"a,b"-"c,d","a,b"-"c,d"',
    '"3-Amino-1,2,4-triazole"-text-0-"3-Amino-1,2,4-triazole"-CD-0,"3-Amino-1,2,4-triazole"-text-0-"3-Amino-1,2,4-triazole"-LS-0',
]

for test in tests:
    row = test.replace(',"' , ';"').split(';')
    print(len(row), row)
```

Giving:

```
2 ['"a,b"-"c,d"', '"a,b"-"c,d"']
2 ['"3-Amino-1,2,4-triazole"-text-0-"3-Amino-1,2,4-triazole"-CD-0', '"3-Amino-1,2,4-triazole"-text-0-"3-Amino-1,2,4-triazole"-LS-0'
```

Answer (score 0):

If the structure is always the same with the comma sandwiched between an integer and the `'"'`, you can use a regular expression:

```
import re

re.split('(?<=[0-9]),(?=")', text)
```